# Send more than one parameter to a web servicee

Tags: iphone, objective-c, vb.net, web-services, cocoa

I'm porting an app from .Net to iPhone and I need to comunicate with a web service. My customer who developed the original app says the web service needs to receive 2 parameters. He sent me this code:

```
Dim A As AcessoWS.AcessoWS Dim ds As New DataSet Try
        A = New AcessoWS.AcessoWS(Webservice)
        ds = A.ClassesAndCombosList(SupplierID, 1)
        If Not ds Is Nothing Then
```

SupplierID and 1 are the 2 parameters. Does anyone knows how these parameters are sent in the request? Body? Headers? Anything else?

Comment: Look at AFNetwork for web requests. It is very easy to include multiple parameters in the request and it takes care of managing the connection in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more of the code, it is hard to determine how the parameters are being sent to the web service.  Do you have access to the other side of the web call to see a valid request?  If you don't, is there documentation to check how the web service required communication?

You could always try and use a Rest client in your browseer.  Firefox has a great Rest client that can be installed as an addon.  You can find it here: http://restclient.net/